# Target click function to links within within a nested <li>

Tags: jquery

Im trying to limit a click function to  links residing only within an `<li>` that has `class="active"` and next another nested `<li>` with `class="scroll"`.

In the below example this would equal to `Block 1-1`+`Block 1-2`.
Im trying with the following which isnt working for me:

JQUERY:

```
$("#header").on('click', "#menu li.active li.scroll a", function(e) { }
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li class="menu-item active" id="menu-item-130">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="scroll menu-item active" id="menu-item-208">
                <a href="#">Block 1-1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="scroll menu-item active" id="menu-item-209">
                <a href="#">Block 1-2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="menu-item" id="menu-item-131">
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li class="scroll menu-item active" id="menu-item-10">
                <a href="#">Block 2-1</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: works fine here when above html wrapped in `id=header` http://jsfiddle.net/mro81u4h/ Do you have an ID=header or is it a `<header>` tag? Please show full html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#menu').on('click', 'li.scroll', function (e) {
    if ($(this).parent().parent().hasClass('active')) alert();
})
```

Heres the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/66wavtaf/

Comment: This won't work if `#menu` is created dynamically. His original code implies that this is dynamic, and the static element is `#header`.

Comment: #menu is just a selector for demonstration. You can use $(document) instead. that will result in same functionality

Comment: If you change that, you need to add `#menu` into the selector argument, otherwise it will delegate to `li.scroll` elements that aren't in `#menu`. In any case, what is your code doing that wouldn't work just as well in the original syntax?